# Dado un lote de n números, contar cuantos son números primos

Tags: python, algoritmos, números-primos

Apenas voy iniciando en la programación y tengo ciertas dudas que me aquejan con cierto ejercicio en python:

> Dado un lote de n números, contar cuantos son números primos.

Si alguien sabe como codificarlo se lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, me temo que aqui no hacemos ni lo deberes ni los ejercicios a nadie. Intentamos ayudar a los usuarios con preguntas **concretas** , reformula tu pregunta  adjuntando el código que has intentado y quizas podramos ayudarte. Un saludo!

Comment: Revertí tu edición, pues parece que indicas dejar la respuesta en la misma pregunta, cosa que no es correcta, yo te invitaría a editar la misma y agregar lo que intentaste y en la zona de respuestas postear tu solución.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Los puedes hacer es iterar la lista de números y utilizar una variable contadora cada ves que de verdadero la `function`, es importante que sepas operar listas.
Una de las operaciones clave de esta `function` es `mod %` ya que este nos permite saber el residuo de una division, lo que nos permite saber si un numero es divisible por otro.

```
# A school method based Python3 program  
# to check if a number is prime 

# function check whether a number  
# is prime or not 
def isPrime(n): 

    # Corner case 
    if (n <= 1): 
        return False

    # Check from 2 to n-1 
    for i in range(2, n): 
        if (n % i == 0): 
            return False

    return True

# Driver Program  
if isPrime(11): 
    print ("true") 
else: 
    print ("false") 

# This code is contributed by Sachin Bisht
```

Te dejo esta referencia para que adaptes el código a tus necesidades.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = int(input("ingrese la cantidad de numeros a operar: "))
cnt_primos = 0
for i in range(x):
    n = int(input("numero: "))
    cnt_divisor = 0
    for divisor in range(1, n+1):
        if n % divisor == 0:
            cnt_divisor = cnt_divisor + 1
    if cnt_divisor == 2:
        cnt_primos = cnt_primos + 1
print('son', cnt_primos, 'primos.')
```

Disculpen, soy nuevo en esto. Aquí dejo la respuesta en concreto para cualquier pregunta parecida.

Answer (score -1):

Esta función devuelve la cantidad de números primos entre dos intervalos de números

```
def Cantidad_Primos(primer_numero,ult_numero):
  num_primos = 0
  for val in range(primer_numero, ult_numero + 1):
    if val > 1: 
        for n in range(2, val): 
            if (val % n) == 0: 
                break
        else: #como no encuentra un break ejecuta la sentencia else
            num_primos=num_primos+1      
  return num_primos

print(Cantidad_Primos(1,7)) #return 4 (2,3,5,7)
```